# Issues with UWP Device Connecting to MySQL

Tags: mysql, vb.net, uwp

I'm having issues connecting a UWP device to MySQL after the latest Windows 10 update.

After doing research, it looks like there's no MySQL connector available that works with the new Windows update.

Everything worked fine before the update, but now I'm receiving this error:

```
{System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Diagnostics.Process, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified.
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectAttrs.get_PID()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.GetValue(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] index, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.GetValue(Object obj, Object[] index)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.SetConnectAttrs()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Authentication.MySqlAuthenticationPlugin.Authenticate(Boolean reset)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Authenticate(String authMethod, Boolean reset)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Open()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Create(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()
   at SLBHandHeldFINAL.Config.Button_Click_1(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you  tried adding the NuGet package System.Diagnostics.Process? It looks like it is missing the dependency...

Comment: @Taylor Grado Does it work now?

Comment: I added the System.Diagnostics.Process and am getting this error:

Could not load file or assembly 'System.Diagnostics.Process, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: I currently have System.Diagnostics.Process Version 4.3.0 installed. Why do I need 4.0.0?